# Deeplinking jQuery-mobile 1.3 and jqm.page.params.js

Tags: jquery-mobile

I tried to update from jqm 1.1 to 1.3.
When a page is changed with page-params (e.g `$.mobile.changePage("#page2?id=xy")`), the page gets changed correctly, but the params do not appear in the Browser Url, so bookmarking or reloading of the page fails because of the missing params.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$.mobile.changePage("#page2?id=xy")`

Comment: This code snippet is exactly what the OP wrote. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround i now use in my onPageChange Event Listener:

```
var correctHash = window.location.hash.replace(/\?.*$|$/, "")  + (data.options.pageData? ("?"+jQuery.param(data.options.pageData)):"");
history.replaceState(null,null,correctHash);
```

this appends the cut off params back to the Hash

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work for me. What does your event listener look like? I tried this:

    $(document).bind('onpagechange', function(event, data) {